# How to render components only once in NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-router

In Nuxt Framework using SPA mod,
I have a default layout:

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <my-header />
    <nuxt />
    <my-footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

In the example above, `<my-header>` and `<my-footer>` are the components I created.

I want them to initialize and render only once.
After changing the router, they will not render again.

Comment: your footer and header wont re-render. they would only re-render if you change your layout

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you provided is located in layouts > default.vue, for example, and that you did not change the default settings within the `.nuxt` folder, it will render only once.

Only what is within the `<nuxt />` will change - that will be the content of your app in general. Basically it will display the page components (used only in layouts - [ref](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt/)).

So in this case, as long as you do not refresh the page the header and footer will not be rerendered. When moving between the pages you might want to use `nuxt-link` ([ref](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/)) and not force the reload (leave it at default settings).

Example `nuxt-link` usage:

```
<nuxt-link to="/about">About page</nuxt-link>
```

The about page would be located in:

pages > about > index.vue

Comment: Thank for your information, but I want it to not re-render as changes between pages :(

Comment: The header and footer will not re-render in this case (as explained above) if you used the `nuxt-link` to switch between the pages.

Comment: Maybe you reload your page! for example by using <a href="NEW_ROUTE"    or  window.location.href="NEW_ROUTE" 

Ss @JakubASuplicki said you should use only <nuxt-link to="MEW_ROUTE"   or
this.$router.push({ name: 'NEW_ROUTE'})  

To not reload page

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me.
I am using nuxt-router.
For example, I use console.log('go here') in created() hook in my-header, when the router pushes to switch between pages, I don't want that component to be re-render(not run code in created())

Comment: @AlberZ How exactly do you switch between pages, can you show an example? Layouts will run only once by default, the first time app initialises, if header and footer are placed in there that means it will mount and create only once. The problem is the way you switch between pages as mentioned before.

Comment: Oh, I have found a reason.
This is because I use my-header in a component, not in the layout.

Comment: Correct, as mentioned above, it should be placed in layouts. Please accept the answer if it is helpful. Thanks